# how to get the type of input in laravel

Tags: javascript, html, laravel, input, types

I have input in my form and I want to save the name, type, and value of that input in my database when the user saves the form.

I'm getting the name and value of the input but can't get the type.

I've tried it with JavaScript and it works. But I want to save it using Laravel in the controller.
Is there any way that I can get the type?

using JavaScript:
document.getElementsByName("name")[0].type
returns "text".

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Without the code it's hard to say ... Maybe you could add the type to the name of the input, and then extract the type at the server. Or include a hidden input which has the type as its value, and name the pairs like `name="name[]"` ..?

Comment: Please provide your code(Controller as well as blade file).

Comment: Controller:
function createForm(Request $request)
    {
        foreach ($request->all() as $key => $value) {
            if ($key != '_token') {
                $file = File::create([
                    'name' => $key,
                    'type' => 'want to get this from input',
                    'value' => $value
                ]);
            }
        }
        return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Form has been created successfully');
    }

Comment: Blade code

<form action="{{ route('user.createForm') }}" method="post">
            @csrf
            <div class="form-group">
                {!! $input->description !!}
            </div>

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
        </form>

Answer (score 1):

Using the built in php function :

[gettype — Get the type of a variable](https://www.php.net/gettype)

See this below pseudo code:

```
$input = "Your Name";

echo gettype($input);
```

Comment: yeah, I tried this one but it returns a string instead of text.

#attributes: array:6 [▼
    "name" => "name"
    "type" => "string"
    "value" => "Carolyn Fisher"
    "updated_at" => "2022-02-17 13:59:26"
    "created_at" => "2022-02-17 13:59:26"
    "id" => 5
  ]

Comment: `gettype` get the type of variable not the type of the form field field in which the value came from

Comment: but I want the type of input field.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing which you can related to each input field is it `name` and it `value`. To have type of each field you can use `hidden` field which will have name like `type_of_name` for a field which has name **name** and `type_of_password` for a field which has name **password** and so on. as all that field will be pass to the request you can access them inside of you controller and get type of each form field by getting input element which as name equal to the field name prefixed with the `type_of`

Here is a sample code

```
<form action="" method="post">
   
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <input type="hidden" name="type_of_name" value="text">

    <input type="password" name="password">
    <input type="hidden" name="type_of_password" value="password">
    {{-- etc. --}}
</form>
```

Comment: but I want to save them in the same row. It'll make things complex for me in the future.

Comment: As I said in the description of my answer you only get two items from each form field when you submit a form it value and the name attribute of that field. You cannot pass other property attached to that field

Comment: yes, I got it. I guess my only option is to use javascript now :)

Comment: Evenly with javascript for each `FormData` property you will only add it name and it value. That will be exactly the same but you won't have the field in you html code and you will handle the submission of your form within javascript